# Python SQLite3 database not saving data Repl.it

Tags: python

I am trying to program an sql database in python that asks for your name and stores it in a database. The problem is that it stores it but then when I reload, the data is gone. Here is the code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('python.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RecordONE (Number REAL, Name TEXT)')
name = input("What is your name?")
def data_entry():
    number = "1234"
    c.execute("INSERT INTO RecordONE (Number, Name) VALUES(?, ?)", (number, name))
    conn.commit()

create_table()
data_entry()

c.close()
conn.close()
```

What could the problem be?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that you put `con.commit()` before you called your functions and actually wrote to the database. Here is a working example:

```
# Imports
import sqlite3
# Establish connection to database
conn = sqlite3.connect('python.db')
c = conn.cursor()
# Create global variable name
name = ""

def create_table():
  global name # Retrieve global variable name
  c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RecordONE (Number REAL, Name TEXT)') # DB execution
  name = input("What is your name?") # Input to global variable name

def data_entry():
  number = "1234"
  c.execute("INSERT INTO RecordONE (Number, Name) VALUES(?, ?)", (number, name)) # Execute sql

# Call functions
create_table()
data_entry()

# Save changes to DB
conn.commit()

# Close connection
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Then you can see the entry you just created in this code:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM RecordONE')
print(c.fetchall())
```

Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: I tried running the code you gave but it still didn't work. Could the editor I am using be the problem? I'm using the online editor Repl.it.

Comment: I ran this on repl.it

Comment: Ill see it again

Comment: It worked once. But when i tried it again, the data disappeared.

Comment: Hmmmm... That's weird